# How can I work "locally" on ASP code using OSX?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, asp

The company I work for recently migrated a Rails project over to ASP. Previously, our front end development team had been working on the Rails project on Macs. The new ASP team us telling is that to work on the ASP project, we need to use Visual Studio on Windows. The ASP team works locally on Windows, and uses TFS for version control.

What I'm wondering is: is there a way for our team to continue using OSX while being able to edit the ASP files, version control the ASP files, compile the ASP files, view the result in a browser, and have other abilities of working locally on ASP files on a Windows machine?

I don't require that the ASP files be run directly in OSX. I'd be fine with those files sitting on a server, and each developer accessing them on that server. The only caveats are that multiple developers need to be able to work on the same files and submit them to version control asynchronously, and we need to be able to do most things to the ASP that we would be able to do if we were running it locally on Windows.

Is there a way to "work locally" on ASP code using OSX, not requiring that the files are actually on the Mac?

Comment: in the end, you are just hacking a kludge together, and it will never work as well as just using native tools. you can certianly work on asp using a plain old text editor and you can access TFS using Team Explorer Everywhere https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=30661 but in the end, you are doing yourself and your team a disservice by trying to do .net dev on a mac. you would not be able to compile/build, debug, use any code-assist features, or manage files in projects/solutions. theres just no good answer to your issue except use MS.

Comment: I agree with @FrankThomas. If you are still keen to work on a Mac, you could run Windows in a virtual machine.  I'd suggest [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) (Open Source) or [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) (Proprietary).  Since I use my MacBook as my primary computer at work, I've used VirtualBox to do [tag:C#] development in Visual Studio.  If you do use this route, extra ram in your computer wouldn't be a bad idea either.

Comment: The new ASP team has been trying to get us to use a VM to make this work. I was thinking that there might be another way, but maybe that's the only way.